# Unknown Display after installing nvidia driver

Tags: graphic-drivers

Asus gaming laptop with 1920x1080p 120hz screen and Nvidia 1070.
Comes up unknown display and locks it at 800x600
if uninstall the driver the screen works fine at the full-res and 120hz

Comment: Can you please describe the steps you took to install the nVidia driver? And the laptop's model might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

In have the same problem.  I always had issues with nvidia drivers like this so I never install them, but this time I needed to install CUDA for development and tried to install on the side, installation was not succesful, I uninstalled all nvidia marked software, but I still have the display "unknown"  and my resolution is off (large fonts etc)  The old laptop is HP and I have a HP external screen connected to it, no idea how to correct it.